# Onclick in HTML using String in URL

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to pass this url in the String variable using HTML button within java but this is not working. Can someone help?

```
String URL = "http://localhost/asp"

out.append("<input type=\"button\" value=\"Refresh4\" onClick=\"window.location.reload(URL)\"/>");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the variable into the string with `+ URL +`:

```
String URL = "http://localhost/asp";
out.append("<input type='button' value='Refresh4' onclick='window.location.reload(" + URL + ")'/>");
```

Also, no need to escape all the `"` you used. In Javascript, you can use `'`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. For some reason this works  out.append("<input type=\"button\" value=\"Refresh\" onClick=\"window.location.reload()\">");  but this is not working  - out.append("<input type=\"button\" value=\"Refresh4\" onClick=\"window.location.reload(\"http://localhost/asp/main.aspx?+"+URL+")\"/>");.. Nothing happens while clicking on the button

Comment: @user7471208 You didn't use the code I posted... Just copy it to your code.